# Cython: size attribute of memoryviews

Tags: python, attributes, cython, memoryview, typed-memory-views

I'm using a lot of 3D memoryviews in Cython, e.g.

```
cython.declare(a='double[:, :, ::1]')
a = np.empty((10, 20, 30), dtype='double')
```

I often want to loop over all elements of `a`. I can do this using a triple loop like

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        for k in range(a.shape[2]):
            a[i, j, k] = ...
```

If I do not care about the indices `i`, `j` and `k`, it is more efficient to do a flat loop, like

```
cython.declare(a_ptr='double*')
a_ptr = cython.address(a[0, 0, 0])
for i in range(size):
    a_ptr[i] = ...
```

Here I need to know the number of elements (`size`) in the array. This is given by the product of the elements in the `shape` attribute, i.e. `size = a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]*a.shape[2]`, or more generally `size = np.prod(np.asarray(a).shape)`. I find both of these ugly to write, and the (albeit small) computational overhead bothers me. The nice way to do it is to use the builtin `size` attribute of memoryviews, `size = a.size`. However, for reasons I cannot fathom, this leads to unoptimized C code, as evident from the annotations html file generated by Cython. Specifically, the C code generated by `size = a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]*a.shape[2]` is simply

```
__pyx_v_size = (((__pyx_v_a.shape[0]) * (__pyx_v_a.shape[1])) * (__pyx_v_a.shape[2]));
```

where the C code generated from `size = a.size` is

```
__pyx_t_10 = __pyx_memoryview_fromslice(__pyx_v_a, 3, (PyObject *(*)(char *)) __pyx_memview_get_double, (int (*)(char *, PyObject *)) __pyx_memview_set_double, 0);; if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_10)) __PYX_ERR(0, 2238, __pyx_L1_error)
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_10);
__pyx_t_14 = __Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr(__pyx_t_10, __pyx_n_s_size); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_14)) __PYX_ERR(0, 2238, __pyx_L1_error)
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_14);
__Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_10); __pyx_t_10 = 0;
__pyx_t_7 = __Pyx_PyIndex_AsSsize_t(__pyx_t_14); if (unlikely((__pyx_t_7 == (Py_ssize_t)-1) && PyErr_Occurred())) __PYX_ERR(0, 2238, __pyx_L1_error)
__Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_14); __pyx_t_14 = 0;
__pyx_v_size = __pyx_t_7;
```

To generate the above code, I have enabled all possible optimizations through [compiler directives](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives), meaning that the unwieldy C code generated by `a.size` cannot be optimized away. It looks to me as though the `size` "attribute" is not really a pre-computed attribute, but actually carries out a computation upon lookup. Furthermore, this computation is quite a bit more involved than simply taking the product over the `shape` attribute. I cannot find any hint of an explanation in the [docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#memoryview-objects-and-cython-arrays).

What is the explanation of this behavior, and do I have a better choice than writing out `a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]*a.shape[2]`, if I really care about this micro optimization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Already by looking at the produced C-code, you can already see that `size` is a property and not a simple C-member. Here is the [original Cython-code for memory-views](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L588):

```
@cname('__pyx_memoryview')
cdef class memoryview(object):
...
   cdef object _size
...
    @property
    def size(self):
        if self._size is None:
            result = 1

            for length in self.view.shape[:self.view.ndim]:
                result *= length

            self._size = result

return self._size
```

It is easy to see, that the product is calculated only once and then cached. Clearly it doesn't play a big role for 3 dimensional arrays, but for a higher number of dimensions caching could become pretty important (as we will see, there are at most 8 dimensions, so it is not that clearly cut, whether this caching is really worth it).

One can understand the decision to lazily calculate the `size` - after all, `size` is not always needed/used and one doesn't want to pay for it. Clearly, there is a price to pay for this laziness if you use the `size` a lot - that is the trade off cython makes.

I would not dwell too long on the overhead of calling `a.size` - it is nothing compared to the  overhead of calling a cython-function from python.

For example, the measurements of @danny measure only this python-call overhead and not the actual performance of the different approaches. To show this, I throw a third function into the mix:

```
%%cython
...
def both():
    a.size+a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]*a.shape[2]
```

which does double amount of the work, but

```
>>> %timeit mv_size
22.5 ns ± 0.0864 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

>>> %timeit mv_product
20.7 ns ± 0.087 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

>>>%timeit both
21 ns ± 0.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

is just as fast. On the other hand:

```
%%cython
...
def nothing():
   pass
```

isn't faster:

```
%timeit nothing
24.3 ns ± 0.854 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

---

In a nutshell: I would use `a.size` because of the readability, assuming that optimizing that would not speed up my application, unless profiling proves something different.

---

**The whole story:** the variable `a` is of type `__Pyx_memviewslice` and not of type `__pyx_memoryview` as one could think. The struct `__Pyx_memviewslice` has the following definition:

```
struct __pyx_memoryview_obj;
typedef struct {
  struct __pyx_memoryview_obj *memview;
  char *data;
  Py_ssize_t shape[8];
  Py_ssize_t strides[8];
  Py_ssize_t suboffsets[8];
} __Pyx_memviewslice;
```

that means, `shape` can be accessed very efficiently by the Cython-code, as it is a simple C-array (btw. I ask my self, what happens if there are more than 8 dimensions? - the answer is: you cannot have more than 8 dimensions).

The member `memview` is where the memory is hold and `__pyx_memoryview_obj` is the C-Extension which is produce from the cython-code we saw above and looks as follows:

```
/* "View.MemoryView":328
 * 
 * @cname('__pyx_memoryview')
 * cdef class memoryview(object):             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 * 
 *     cdef object obj
 */
struct __pyx_memoryview_obj {
  PyObject_HEAD
  struct __pyx_vtabstruct_memoryview *__pyx_vtab;
  PyObject *obj;
  PyObject *_size;
  PyObject *_array_interface;
  PyThread_type_lock lock;
  __pyx_atomic_int acquisition_count[2];
  __pyx_atomic_int *acquisition_count_aligned_p;
  Py_buffer view;
  int flags;
  int dtype_is_object;
  __Pyx_TypeInfo *typeinfo;
};
```

So, `Pyx_memviewslice` is not really a Python object -it is kind of convenience wrapper, which caches important data, like `shape` and `stride` so this information can be accessed fast and cheap.

What happens when we call `a.size`?  First, `__pyx_memoryview_fromslice` is called which does some additional reference counting and some further stuff and returns the member `memview` from the `__Pyx_memviewslice`-object.

Then the property `size` is called on this returned memoryview, which accesses the cached value in `_size` as have been shown in the Cython code above.

It looks as if the python-programmers introduced a shortcut for such important information as `shape`, `strides` and `suboffsets`, but not for the `size` which is probably not so important - this is the reason for cleaner C-code in the case of `shape`.

Comment: Thank you! `size` being a pure Python property fits my observations. From your link, it would seem as though `shape` is also such a property, and that it returns a `tuple`. Though in practice, `a.shape` returns a `Py_ssize_t` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The generated C code for `a.size` looks fine.

It has to interface with Python because memory views are python extension types. `size` on the memory view is a python attribute and gets converted to `ssize_t`. That is all the C code does. The conversion can be avoided by typing the `size` variable as `Py_ssize_t` rather than `ssize_t`.

So there is not anything in the C code that looks unoptimised - it's just looking up an attribute on a python object, size on a memory view in this case.

Here are results of micro-benchmark for the two methods.

Setup:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
cimport cython
cython.declare(a='double[:, :, ::1]')
a = np.empty((10, 20, 30), dtype='double')

def mv_size():
    return a.size
def mv_product():
    return a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]*a.shape[2]
```

Results:

```
%timeit mv_size
10000000 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ns per loop

%timeit mv_product
10000000 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ns per loop
```

Performance is pretty much identical.

The product method is purely C code which matters if it needs to be executed in parallel, but otherwise there is no performance benefit over memory view `size`.

Comment: I will test the performance difference later myself. If there truly are no difference, there is of course no problem. Why `a.shape[0]` produces much cleaner C code than `a.size` remains a mystery to me though.

Comment: Also, I do not get why it matters if the code is to be executed in parallel. And it is indeed...

Comment: The `a.size` C code is pretty clean - as clean as any C code that Cython generates :) There is more of it because of the Python interaction and error checking that Cython does.

Comment: For 'parallelisation', I meant outside of python, ie with Cython's `prange` and openmp interaction. That requires that the parallel code is C only, no python interaction. That means memory views cannot be used so whether size is a product of memory view share or an attribute does not matter - memory views cannot be used in `prange`. If using python threading then there are no restrictions.