# How to prevent a __Pyx_MemoryView_Len(__pyx_v_a) Python Interaction in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I have a simple Cython function, which gets the length of a memoryview:

```
cdef int get_length(int[:] a):
    return len(a)
```

I am compiling the compiling the code with the `annotate=True` directive, to let me see where Cython has some Python interaction.

The resulting html contains this text, for the `return len(a)` line:

```
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_MemoryView_Len(__pyx_v_a); 
  __pyx_r = __pyx_t_1;
  goto __pyx_L0;
```

Such Python interaction is supposed to be slow. Is there a way for me to prevent the Python interaction? I have tried `a.shape[0]`, but that did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not worry about that, `__Pyx_MemoryView_Len` is as fast as it gets, because [it is defined](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/7a31638983ebd1e6d1a4b3eb652e30ed58fcea75/Cython/Utility/MemoryView_C.c#L7) as:

```
typedef struct {
  struct {{memview_struct_name}} *memview;
  char *data;
  Py_ssize_t shape[{{max_dims}}];
  ...
} {{memviewslice_name}};

// used for "len(memviewslice)"
#define __Pyx_MemoryView_Len(m) (m.shape[0])
```

The color of this line isn't yellow but yellowish - which mostly means that this it results not in pure C-code, but that some `_Pyx_XXX` functionality is used, which often isn't bad for the performance at all.

There is no Python-interaction - after the C-preprocessor-pass, it will be seen by the C-compiler as if you have written:

```
return a.shape[0]
```

which leads to a white line by the way.

If you are also interested in the size of a multi-dimensional memview, then [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49919768/5769463) might be worth reading.

---

Annotate shows the definition of the function as a yellow line. However, only the cost when module is loaded (and it is paid once and not every time the function is called) is responsible for the "yellow" color.

Take a look at the resulting C-code:

```
static int __pyx_f_9my_module_get_length(__Pyx_memviewslice __pyx_v_a) {
  int __pyx_r;
  __Pyx_RefNannyDeclarations
  __Pyx_RefNannySetupContext("get_length", 0);

  /* "my_module.pyx":5
 * 
 * cdef int get_length(int[:] a):
 *     return a.shape[0]             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 */
  __pyx_r = (__pyx_v_a.shape[0]);
  goto __pyx_L0;

  /* "my_module.pyx":4
 *     return 3. * a
 * 
 * cdef int get_length(int[:] a):             # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 *     return a.shape[0]
 */

  /* function exit code */
  __pyx_L0:;
  __Pyx_RefNannyFinishContext();
  return __pyx_r;
}
```

`RefNannyXXXX` is only active when build with [`CYTHON_REFNANNY`-defined.](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-refnanny)

There is also another code shown by the `annotate`-tool, which corresponds to `cdef int get_length(int[:] a):` :

```
/* … */
  __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyDict_NewPresized(0); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(1, 1, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
  if (PyDict_SetItem(__pyx_d, __pyx_n_s_test, __pyx_t_1) < 0) __PYX_ERR(1, 1, __pyx_L1_error)
  __Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
```

However, this code is part of `__pyx_pymod_exec_XXXXX`/`PyInit_XXXXX` and which is only called once, when the module is loaded. Actually, I'm not sure how this is related to `get_length` and why this is needed, but because the costs are so small I never cared enough to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Why is the cost only when the module is loaded? I'm not a C-programmer.

Comment: @Ginger I have added some explanation